# Criteria API: Column Names from Either Root or Join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have either a `Root` or a `Join` as the root of a Criteria API query.

```
    // A possible variable FROM (either Root or Join, both derive from it)
    From from = null;

    // Case 1
    Root<TraineeSearch> root = criteriaQuery.from(TraineeSearch.class);
    from = root;
    // Case 2: conditionally join on PLANS_T
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(criteria.getOptionalString())) {
        Join<TraineeSearch, Plans> traineeSearchPlansJoin = root.join("plans", JoinType.INNER);
        from = traineeSearchPlansJoin;
    }
```

You can see that either I'm querying straight on `TraineeSearch` or on the Join between `TraineeSearch & Plans`. Table 1 is always present.

Then I need to test some columns that are in `TraineeSearch` (Table 1) so they're always available. I do this on the `from` which is derived by this point.

```
    Predicate where = cb.conjunction();

    // These are Table 1 columns, always present
    where = cb.and(where, cb.or(cb.equal(from.get("active"), true),  
                          cb.isNotNull(from.get("currentPlan"))));
```

When I have a JOIN, my error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  
           with the the given name [active] on this ManagedType [app.domain.Plans]
```

Do I need an alias of some kind? But then how would I write my Where predicate generically?

**Update**

The final SQL needs to be either

(1) `select .. from trainee_search_vw where current = 'Y'` or

(2) `select .. from trainee_search_vw ts, plans_t p where ts.current = 'Y'`

(for (2), there will be other `Plans` fields in the Join, but let's solve the immediate error first on the Table 1 column)

Fields like `current` are always included.

The domain objects are

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAINEE_SEARCH_VW")
public class TraineeSearch {
   //...

   private List<Plans> plans;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRAINEE_NED_ID", referencedColumnName = "NED_ID")    
public List<Plans> getPlans() {
    return plans;
}

public void setPlans(List<Plans> plans) {
    this.plans = plans;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLANS_T")
public class Plans {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Could you please show `TraineeSearch` and `Plans` entities and the final sql that you want to build using the criteria api.

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to initialize JOINS is to use the metamodel.

In eclipse you can activate the automatic generation by clicking on the project / properties / JPA / source canonical and selecting src.

A join with metamodel prevents you from crossing tables using wrong fields and would be as follows:

```
Join<TraineeSearch, Plans> traineeSearchPlansJoin = root.join(TraineeSearch_.plans, JoinType.INNER);
```